# How to perform a make install without any apt confirmation

Tags: apt, make

When installing packages with `apt` one can skip the confirmation prompt by specifying `-y`. However, sometimes when using the `make` command, that confirmation prompt will show up if depencies are missing.

How can I speficy to the `make` command that I don't want a confirmation when using the package manager? This is problematic in an automated environment

I can't find a equivalent `make install -y`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To skip `apt`’s confirmation prompt, write

```
APT::Get::Assume-Yes "true";
```

in a file, and set the `APT_CONFIG` variable to point to the file:

```
APT_CONFIG=/path/to/snippet.conf make install
```

This is equivalent to specifying `-y` on the `apt` command line.

In an automated environment where you don’t ever want prompts, you might as well write the setting to `/etc/apt/apt.conf` or a configuration file under `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d`; then you won’t need to set `APT_CONFIG`.

Answer (score -1):

You can

```
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
```

before calling `make install`.

(PS: Kinda strange of any `make install` to call apt... but there's very much software under the sun, so I'm not surprised)

Comment: Unfortunatly I am still getting the prompt! I may need to modify the makefile myself.

Comment: I stand by a makefile not having any business calling into package managers...

Comment: I'm not the maintainer but I agree

Comment: Setting `DEBIAN_FRONTEND` doesn’t affect `apt`’s prompts.